# Is there any way to get old Windows kernel drivers?

Tags: windows, kernel

I'm working through "Practical Reverse Engineering" and absolutely loving it so far. However, some of the exercises involve "decompiling" some Windows kernel files (like KeInitializeDpc, KeInitializeApc, ObFastDereferenceObject, etc) and I don't run Windows.
I haven't been able to find any of the drivers online nor have I found any reliable sites from which I can get a Windows (anything between XP and 7) iso. Is there anywhere that I could get either of these things?

Comment: In a lot of countries it is legal to "unbundle" MS software from the hardware it came with. If you live in such a country you can simply buy an old Windows version on eBay or else where they sell them for a few bucks.

Comment: Obviously, this isn't a solution for everyone but with an MSDN/Visual Studio Professional subscription (?$500ish/year?) you can download isos for XP/Vista/7/8.1/10/11. Downloading from Microsoft and verifying the hash is the safest way to get those files. You might be able to get the "Windows XP mode" VM for free - it was a big marketing point when they released it.

Comment: You can get 7/8.1/10 from here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/ .. no account required

Comment: @MegaTonnage thanks so much!